# Create Deeply Nested Rails Associations in One Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a user form on my welcome page. As the user form gets submitted, I want to create a website record that belongs to the user and also a page record that belongs to that website.

I'm trying to use fields_for but I'm not sure what I'm doing correctly or incorrectly.

```
# welcome.html.erb

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.text_field :name' %>
     </div>
     <div>
         <%= f.email_field :email %>
     </div>
     <div>
         <%= f.password_field :password %>
     </div>
     <div>
         <%= f.fields_for :website do |website_fields| %>
             <%= website_fields.text_field :name, value: 'Untitled website' %>
         <% end %>
     </div>
     <div>
         <%= f.fields_for :page do |page_fields| %>
             <%= page_fields.text_field :name, value: 'Untitled page' %>
             <%= page_fields.text_field :content, class: 'js-PageContentHiddenField', value: 'Page content' %>
         <% end %>
     </div>
     <div>
         <%= f.submit 'Create account' %>
     </div>
 <% end %>
```

The pages controller looks like this...

```
# pages_controller.rb

def welcome
    @user = User.new
    @website = @user.websites.new
    @page = @user.websites.pages.new
end
```

My routes are as follows...

```
# routes.rb

resources :users do
    resources :websites do
        resources :pages
    end
end
```

The models look like this...

```
# User model

has_many :websites, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :pages, through: :websites
accepts_nested_attributes_for :websites
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages

# Website model

belongs_to :user
has_many :pages, :dependent => :destroy

# Page model

belongs_to :website
```

And finally my users controller...

```
# User controller

def create
    @user = User.new(shared_params)
    @website = @user.websites.new(website_params)
    @page = @website.pages.new(page_params)

    if @user.save
        auto_login(@user)
        @redirect_to user_website_page_path
    else
        # redirect to wherever
    end
end

private

    def shared_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :name)
    end

    def website_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :user_id)
    end

    def page_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :website_id)
    end
```

The problem I'm having now is that the user name is being saved as the page and website name etc. It's some problem with my params I think. Also, I'm not sure how to set the redirect to redirect to the page after it's been created.

I've been playing around with various configurations for weeks now and I can't crack this. I can't stress how little I know what I'm doing here, would really love some help!

Comment: So you want to get it created automatically or the user will enter the details in form for those records? Because if you use nested fields that means the user will be entering the details.

Comment: Hey, I've just updated the question after I fixed some issues. I'm using hidden_field for the fields_for fields with default or generated content. The website can be created automatically but the page has some user generated content that I'm adding to the field with JS.

Comment: So why don't you use a callback to created the website and page?

Comment: I don't even know what a callback is :) Can you explain how that might help? Btw, I've just updated the question with some extra info about my params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Callbacks** are methods that get called at certain moments of an object's life cycle. With callbacks it is possible to write code that will run whenever an Active Record object is created, saved, updated, deleted, validated, or loaded from the database.

So as you need to create a `website` and a `page` when the `user` is being created the you can use a `after_create` or `before_create` callback. `after_create` gets executed after the object is created and the `before_create` callback gets executed before the object is being created.

So in your `User` model what you can do is:

```
after_create :create_website_and_page

def create_website_and_page
  website = websites.build(name: 'Untitled Website')
  page = website.pages.build(name: 'Untitled Page', content: 'Page Content')
  website.save # This will automatically save the associated page too
end
```

So as soon as your user is created the `website` and `page` will also be created.

To get the `content` for the `page` from the form you can do:

In `User` model:

```
attr_accessor :page_content
```

This will create a virtual attribute on the `user` object which will not exist in database. Now in your `form`:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :page_content, class: 'js-PageContentHiddenField' %>
```

So append the content from javascript in this field. Now in your controller permit this attribute too:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :name, :page_content)
```

And then finally in the method we wrote above `create_website_and_page` change the line to this:

```
page = website.pages.build(name: 'Untitled Page', content: page_content)
```

This should do the required.

If you still wish to use the `nested_form` for any reason then the mistake you are doing is the `params`. Just place a `debugger` on the top of your create action and check the `params`. So to permit the parameters of website and page you have to do:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :name, website_attributes: [:name], page_attributes: [:name, :website_id, :content])
end
```

but you will never get the `website_id` in `params` as you are creating that also from the same `form`. And also the `user_id` will not be required to be permitted as it will automatically get associated in case of the nested forms.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, very interesting. I tried the after_create callback but I'm getting an error "undefined method `build' for #<Website". Any ideas?

Comment: Oh I made a mistake for building the `page` it should be `page = website.pages.build`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Dude that's insane, you just saved me weeks of pulling my hair out, thanks so much. One last thing, is it possible to inject the page content somehow? I need to get the page content from user generated content in a div.

Comment: Updated the answer. Try that.